# read a file and use the data to make a variable

Tags: lua

So I'm trying to read a file, written with the format of a table:

```
({loop=true, test=1})
```

So basicly I want to read this data with this function:

```
function readAll(file)
local f = assert(io.open(file, "rb"))
local content = f:read("*all")
f:close()
return content
end
```

after I got the content of the file I use table.insert to store my data in an existing table..

but it seems like it stores my data as a string in the table, so if I try to get the data like this:

```
print(tablename.loop)
```

it returns nil, cause it hasn't made the table as I wanted it, it just pasted it as a string.
if I unpack the table I get the exact same thing as the code field at the top. A string.

So I try to insert it in the table, as valid variables, that I can read then easily with tablename.loop etc.

Sorry for my probably bad english.. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: `tablename = assert((loadstring or load)("return "..readAll(file)))(); print(tablename.loop)`

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Egor Skriptunoff. this is the solution I was looking for <3

since he only made a comment, I'll write his solution down again:

```
tablename = assert((loadstring or load)("return "..readAll(file)))(); print(tablename.loop)
```

everyone have a nice day!